# ML.NET LightGbm re-train (append new training data)

Tags: lightgbm, ml.net

I have used the Model Builder to create ML.Net model. The Model Builder selected LightGbm as the trainer.
This all works fine. I now want to retrain the model by appending new training data to the existing model.
I don't want to have to train the model from scratch every time with the new data appended to the old training data, as over a period of a year to two the training data could be many hundreds of gigabytes. I cannot find any examples of how to re-train a model using LightGbm. Please give some examples of how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like the LightGbm training isn't one of the ones that, currently, can be retrained from [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/retrain-model-ml-net).

If you want this ability maybe try to use the AutoML API directly instead of with Model Builder. Then you can specify what trainers it can use.

Comment: Thanks. The results for LbfgsMaximumEntropy wern't that much different in the Model Builder, so I'll give it a try.